# VSCode wont run code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Screenshot of error that I get

[image]

> The term 'gcc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I have the code runner and C/C++ packs installed. But for some reason, I always get an error similar to this regardless of what I try to do. I've tried reinstalling VSCode, but that didn't fix anything.

Comment: Do you have a compiler installed?

Comment: GCC is clearly not in your path.  You probably don't have it.  VSCode simply SHELLS to the stuff you already have.  Support for your "code runner?" and C/C++ isnt "Install GCC and everything else it needs.".  If you can't build at the command line (without VSCode), then VSCode won't succeed either.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt realize that you needed a compiler. I thought it worked like visual studio 2022.

Comment: Nope.. I know you get it now.  VS2022 comes with one.. VSCode does not.  Good luck! :)

Comment: See [C/C++ for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) for an example on how to add a compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install GCC (or whichever C/C++ compiler you want to use) and put the directory containing it in your system `PATH` (usually this is done for you by the installer program / package manager).

Unlike Visual Studio, VS Code does not come with a compiler.